# Flutter Web - space bar key doesn't work in TextFields

Tags: flutter, textfield

whenever I try to press space bar inside a TextField of a Flutter Web Release it doesn't do anything. This occurs on ANY browser except for chrome.

I already tried this "fix":

```
return MaterialApp(
      shortcuts: {
        LogicalKeySet(LogicalKeyboardKey.space): ActivateIntent(),
      },
```

And also I upgraded to flutter 2.10, which was a fix to some people. Sadly not for me, so I'm really happy about help.

The issues sometimes goes away if the Site is reloaded several times.

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.10.2, on macOS 11.1 20C69 darwin-arm, locale
en-DE)
• Flutter version 2.10.2 
• Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
• Framework revision 097d3313d8 (5 days ago), 2022-02-18 19:33:08 -0600
• Engine revision a83ed0e5e3
• Dart version 2.16.1
• DevTools version 2.9.2

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /Users/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-31, build-tools 31.0.0
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android
      Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7281165)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[!] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 12.5.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    ! Flutter recommends a minimum Xcode version of 13.
      Download the latest version or update via the Mac App Store.
    • CocoaPods version 1.11.2

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7281165)

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • Chrome (web) • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 98.0.4758.102

[✓] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available
```

Comment: Do you fix it? I have the same error and I tried  that solutions.

Comment: i am having the same problem. Were you able to solve it?